# What's the power level of the divine lance corporal angels?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

All the power levels of the demon clan are stated; from the original demon to Chandler and Cusack, albions, gray, green, blue, ochre, orange, copper, red and white demons and the demons of the ten commandments. For the angels, it's also stated the power level of the archangels, and those of the divine soldier angels. However, I can't find anywhere the power level of divine lance corporals angels like Nerobasta and Jelamet.

What's the power level of the divine lance corporal angels?